# How to make Jenkins/TeamCity email notifiers work on corporate network ? What could be possible network issues?

Tags: smtp, jenkins

1. Whenever I try to test the Jenkins/TeamCity email notifier, I get a 
   java.net.Connectexception:Connection timed out. The computer is on corporate network. 
   Despite turning off the firewall on the computer, it did not work. I am done trying 
   gmail/yahoo settings.
2. A little bit background, I got the same exception from TeamCity's email notifier 
   previously from some other computer. That computer was also on the same network.
3. Also, I have tried sending an email programatically based on these guidelines. 
   http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ . It 
   works from my home network but not from the corporate network. Same exception as above 
   on corporate network.
4. Based on the above facts, I am not able to draw any specific conclusion related to the 
   network problem. And thus, I cannot redirect the issue to related personnel. Screenshot 
   is attached for the details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to test your SMTP communication using telnet: [How to Use Telnet to Test SMTP Communication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)

Looks like you have some communication problem between the machines inside your corporate network and the SMTP server.

Comment: Awesome link. I was able to debug a "Badly Formatted Address" using this. Much Thanks

Comment: The option that worked for me is to get the IP address of the machine that hosts CI. Add that to MS Exchange Server's relay list. That resolved my issue.